# Logistic Regression Error in R - Mostly Binary Variables

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am trying to do a logistic regression in R. I am looking at the relationship between a binary categorical variable (low birthweight) and various other categorical variables (most are binary, some are not--("smoke" and "mat_BMI_cat2")).

When I type in this code, I always get an error.

```
logit_Mod <-glm(low_bw ~ medical_factors__anemia + medical_factors__eclampsia + m_diabetes + m_hypchron + m_hypreg + smoke + mat_BMI_cat2, data= trainingData, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

I get this error:

```
Error in family$linkfun(mustart) : Argument mu must be a nonempty numeric vector
```

I am a bit confused what this error means and where I should go from here.

Thank you!

Comment: Most likely one of the variables of your dataset has NA values? Maybe empty values?

Comment: Have you tried: logit_Mod <-glm(low_bw ~ medical_factors__anemia + medical_factors__eclampsia + m_diabetes + m_hypchron + m_hypreg + smoke + mat_BMI_cat2, data= trainingData, family = binomial(link = "logit"), **na.action=na.exclude**)

Comment: @Tiffany yes, I just tried that and received the same error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35594236/logistic-regression-error-in-r  this might help

Comment: It will be very hard to help you without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)